# Matrix multiplication and eigen vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $a$ is a right eigenvector of $S$ and $R^T$ with eigenvalue $1$. How would determine $a^TRSa$? Is $Sa$ simply $a$? Any hints that apply here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does $a'$ stand for $a^T$?

Comment: Yes. It stands for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the definition of right eigenvectors $S a=\lambda a$ and $R^T a=\lambda a$ (with $\lambda =1$). $R^T a= a$ can be written as $(R^T a)^T=a^T$, or $a^T (R^T)^T=a^T$, or $a^TR=a^T$ So $a^TRSa=(a^TR)(Sa)=a^Ta$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.